# Android - java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed - Is there a solution to resolve this exception for all?

Tags: java, android, exception, runtimeexception

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

     private Camera mCamera;

     private CameraPreview mPreview;

     private FrameLayout mFramePreview;

     private boolean mSafeToTakePicture;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

         Bundle bundle = savedInstanceState;
         if (savedInstanceState == null) {
             bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         }

         mFramePreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

         mSafeToTakePicture = false;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();

         // Create an instance of Camera
         mCamera = getCameraInstance();
         Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

         List<Camera.Size> supportedSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
         int max = 0;
         int index = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < supportedSizes.size(); i++){
             Camera.Size s = supportedSizes.get(i);
             int size = s.height * s.width;
             if (size > max) {
                 index = i;
                 max = size;
             }
         }
         params.setPictureSize(supportedSizes.get(index).width,      supportedSizes.get(index).height);
         mCamera.setParameters(params);
                   mCamera.getParameters().setPictureSize(supportedSizes.get(index).width, supportedSizes.get(index).height);

         // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
         mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
         mFramePreview.addView(mPreview);
         mSafeToTakePicture = true;

         mFramePreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 if (mSafeToTakePicture) {
                     takePhoto();
                     mFramePreview.setOnClickListener(null);
                     mSafeToTakePicture = false;
                 }
             }
         });
     }

     public void takePhoto() {
         mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onAutoFocus(boolean b, Camera pCamera) {
                 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, picture);
             }
         });
     }

     final Camera.PictureCallback picture = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
         @Override
         public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
             /* save picture... */
         }
     };
}
```

An exception sometimes happens when I take a picture.

> RuntimeException->"takePicture failed" (@android.hardware.Camera:native_takePicture:-2), (@android.hardware.Camera:takePicture:1833), (@android.hardware.Camera:takePicture:1778), (@fr.selic.thuit.activities.CameraActivity$2:onAutoFocus:213), (@android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler:handleMessage:1283), (@android.os.Handler:dispatchMessage:111), (@android.os.Looper:loop:207), (@android.app.ActivityThread:main:5728), (@java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:-2), (@com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller:run:789), (@com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit:main:679),

Comment: We need more information, explain with more detail what the problem is and include logcat error.

Comment: Can you share the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: I edited the post, do not hesitate if you want more information

Comment: If possible, show your activity where this problem occurs. The small piece of code you provided doesn't help much. The preview must be started before you can take a picture, are you doing that first?

Comment: It is impossible for the picture to be taken before opening the preview. I added code, I hope this will help.